# What does it mean?? var timer = $.timer(function () { });

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a javascript code. Can anyone explain to me what does the code meant? Especially the $.timer?

```
var timer = $.timer(function () {
    nextAction();
});
```

and this, I believed timer is a class calling sub member but what is time: 1000?

```
timer.set({time : 1000, autostart: true });
```

Comment: I think this is an alternative for `setTimeout` in javascript

Comment: it is a timer where it ticks the function nextAction();

Answer (score 0):

It calls the nextAction() every second.
Check here [jquery timer](https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer)

Comment: Your link is outdated, it moved to https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer last february.

Comment: Thanks. I edited it. I had this bookmarked from some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.timer()

$.timer( [ action ] , [ time ], [ autostart ] )
```

**action** A Function to be called by the timer.

**time** A Number determining how long between actions in milliseconds.

**autostart** A Boolean indicating whether to start the timer. Defaults to false.

Refer

[This project is on Github](https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer)